# Can I make a struct that works with both values and borrowed references to a trait?

Tags: rust, traits, borrow-checker

I want to make a struct that wraps another type but can take both owned and borrowed version of values that implement a given trait.

For example, let's say I have the trait `Foobar`:

```
trait Foobar {
    fn foobar(&self);
}
```

I now want to make a struct that wraps values or borrowed references of this trait:

```
struct FoobarWrapper<T: Foobar> {
    wrapped: T,
    extra_stuff: Stuff
}
```

Here, I want FoobarWrapper to work with both `Baz` and `&Baz` given that `impl Foobar for Baz`.

I have come up with one solution that might work but I don't know if it's idiomatic and that's to simply do:

```
impl<'a, T: Foobar> Foobar for &'a T  {
    fn foobar(&self) {
        (*self).foobar()
    }
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, this makes any reference to a value that implements Foobar also an implementor of Foobar. But is this the way you're supposed to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your solution is probably fine if you can support it. `Iterator` does the same thing with

```
impl<'a, I> Iterator for &'a mut I where I: Iterator + ?Sized
```

You should probably also add the `?Sized` bound too, for flexibility.

Comment: The `?Sized`, is that because it doesn't really matter whether the target is sized or not if you're taking it by reference?

Comment: @EmilEriksson By default all bounds have an implicit `Sized` attribute, which prevents taking unsized types. If, however, you only use the bound through an indirection (eg. `&T` or `Box<T>`), this is unwanted and `?Sized` removes the restriction.